# Show MS office docs in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, binary, ms-office

I get a return from webservices as JSON and there is a binary file which represents a Word docx.
From there I need to show this somehow in a embeded object in the webpage, however I can't find the solution how to do this.
Found: [How to build PDF file from binary string returned from a web-service using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876000/how-to-build-pdf-file-from-binary-string-returned-from-a-web-service-using-javas)

This kind of work but says missing plugin, while I have office installed on my pc.

What I try to do is similair as I do with images:

```
var $image = $("<img/>", {
  src: "data:" + files._type + ";base64," + files._thumb,
  id: "img_" + files.id,
  title: files.name
})
```

what I tried is as on the link, but get the missing plugin.
I already have the binary data on the client and can do with it what I want, but cant see it in the page, but code behind its there