# InvalidStateError in internet explorer 11 during blob creation

Tags: javascript

I'm getting an `InvalidStateError` at the blob creation line on IE 11. Needless to say, it works in Chrome and Firefox. 
I can see that the binary data is my client side. Are there any alternatives to download this as a file?

```
var request = new ActiveXObject("MicrosoftXMLHTTP");
request.open("post", strURL, true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/html");
addSecureTokenHeader(request);
request.responseType = 'blob';

request.onload = function(event) {
    if (request.status == 200) {
        var blob = new Blob([request.response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        var link = document.querySelector('#sim');
        link.setAttribute('href', url);

        var filename =  request.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
        $('#sim').attr("download", filename);
        $(link).trigger('click');
        fireEvent(link, 'click');
    } else {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

After instantiating an `XmlHttpRequest`  with `xhr.responseType = "blob"`
I was getting an `InvalidStateError`. 
However, moving `xhr.responseType = "blob"` to `onloadstart` solved it for me! :)

```
xhr.onloadstart = function(ev) {
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Spent some time on this and actually found out adding `new Uint8Array` works:

```js
var blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(request.response)], {type: 'application/pdf'});
```

Comment: This throws error "SCRIPT5082: Typed array constructor argument is invalid" , my god I hate IE.

Answer (score 3):

Is not a elegant way but it works on IE8 - IE11:

```js
var myForm = document.createElement("form");

myForm.method = "POST";
myForm.action = strURL;
myForm.target = "_blank";

var myInput = document.createElement("input");
myInput.type = "text";
myInput.name = "sim";
myInput.value = JSON.stringify(/*data to post goes here*/);
myForm.appendChild(myInput);

document.body.appendChild(myForm);
myForm.submit();
$(myForm).hide();
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but the reason I adopted the above method was because I am not able to send huge amounts of data using this approach.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a BlobBuilder in that case.

From: https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/294#issuecomment-104029716

```
try {
   blob = new Blob([result], { type: 'application/pdf' });
}
catch (e) {
   // Old browser, need to use blob builder
   window.BlobBuilder = window.BlobBuilder ||
                        window.WebKitBlobBuilder ||
                        window.MozBlobBuilder ||
                        window.MSBlobBuilder;
   if (window.BlobBuilder) {
       var bb = new BlobBuilder();
       bb.append(result);
       blob = bb.getBlob("application/pdf");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After much searching this worked for me on IE, Edge and Chrome

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.onloadstart = function (ev) {
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
  };

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
      if (!window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(xhr.response);
        var aLink = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(aLink);
        aLink.href = url;
        aLink.download = filename;
        aLink.click();
      } else {
        var fileData = [xhr.response];
        blobObject = new Blob(fileData);
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blobObject, filename);
      }
    }
  };
```