# Working around IE11 blob creation failure / InvalidStateError

Tags: javascript, blob, internet-explorer-11

In the following question: [InvalidStateError in internet explorer 11 during blob creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29677339/invalidstateerror-in-internet-explorer-11-during-blob-creation)

...a developer is trying to use data returned from an AJAX call (w/jQuery) in Internet Explorer to forced a download of a PDF. I am trying to implement the same logic.

One member answers:

```
var myForm = document.createElement("form");

myForm.method = "POST";
myForm.action = strURL;
myForm.target = "_blank";

var myInput = document.createElement("input");
myInput.type = "text";
myInput.name = "sim";
myInput.value = JSON.stringify(/*data to post goes here*/);
myForm.appendChild(myInput);

document.body.appendChild(myForm);
myForm.submit();
$(myForm).hide();
```

I believe I need to implement this work-around. My question is specific.

Question: What is the strURL variable supposed to be? I have used an empty string, the same URL as the web page, a web service method URL that explicitly accepts POSTs. I cannot get this to work and would appreciate any suggestions. Thank you.