# Change image into Blob is not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Changing the image into blob by using this below code.

```js
changeImageIntoBlob = getImageResponse => {
 var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
 var binaryData = [];
 binaryData.push(getImageResponse);
 var image = urlCreator.createObjectURL(
   new Blob(binaryData, { type: "jpeg/png" })
 );

 this.setState({
   image
 });
};
```

In the above code getImageResponse param should be like this

```
Blob {size: 144425, type: "image/jpeg"}
```

its working fine in chrome, firefox and EDGE but this one is now working in IE11, the error that occurs in IE is `InvalidStateError` and also added the error in image below for ur reference.

[image: Error facing in IE11]

Help me to figure it out.

Comment: anything [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29677339/invalidstateerror-in-internet-explorer-11-during-blob-creation) help?

Comment: @JaromandaX no bro already tried but not help, so that I came up with the question

Comment: Are you sure the error comes from this part of the code? The errors says it comes from something called `add`, here nothing is called `add`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this function. I'm not sure what is the format of your `getImageResponse` . If it is a dataURI, something like this

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOV....
```

Then you can try this

```
dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
      var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(",")[1]);
      var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
      var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
      for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
      }
      return new Blob([ab], { type: "image/jpeg" }); // change the type here into the type you want
    },
```

Comment: this is how my getImageResponse look like -> Blob {size: 144425, type: "image/jpeg"}