# Render PDF streamed from Web-Service

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pdf, download

Web-Service that streams the PDF file:

```
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Cache-Control: public');
header("Content-length: " . $filesize); 
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$name}");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');  
ob_start();
fpassthru($fp);
$response = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
return $response;
```

jQuery code where the request is initiated and response is utilized:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "/xxx/xxx/1/xxx/5",
      type: "GET",
      async:   true,
      dataType: 'binary',
      headers:{'Content-Type':'application/pdf',
                'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest',
      },
      processData: false,
      success: function(data,status,xhr) {
        var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = fileURL;
        a.download = "Testing.pdf";
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        $(window).on('focus', function(e) {
          $('a').remove();
        });
      },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
           console.log("fail");
      }
```

The PDF file is generated perfectly, and opens automatically. The only problem here is the PDF content comes empty when should have text!

Does anybody have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the PDF you're sending doesn't have the text you're saying it should. If it just wasn't adding it, I would expect to see a corrupted PDF, so the fact it's working aside from this text implies it's not there to begin with.

Comment: There is text there, for sure!

Comment: @Bruno `jQuery.ajax()` does not have standard option for `dataType:"binary"` without adjusting `$.ajax()` source , see https://gist.github.com/SaneMethod/7548768 . Try using native `XMLHttpRequest` , see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876000/how-to-build-pdf-file-from-binary-string-returned-from-a-web-service-using-javas/ .

Comment: @Bruno How have you confirmed this? PHP doesn't randomly remove bits and pieces from files on its own. Certainly not pieces of text when PHP doesn't really have a context of what a PDF actually is.

Comment: @Jon I checked because I have another WS for testing, and on this one i made the XHR request and i got the pdf perfectly!

Comment: I'm not using xhr requests due the WS returns a json object!

Comment: @Bruno are you saying one environment works and another doesn't?

Comment: yes, and i don't know why

Comment: Seriously, have you checked the PDF on the environment that you're having problems with.

Comment: why do you need ajax for this in the first place? just use `window.location`

Comment: _"the WS returns a json object!"_ Where is `json` returned from `php` ? Should `return` be replaced with `echo` ? Is response`binary`or`json` ?

Comment: The situation here is, i have a document which is encrypted when uploaded, and when the user requests the WS first i need to decrypt and after send to the user. What is the best way to send the document to the user? i can't use window.location, because in this case i would need to recreate the decrypted file in a temporary folder at least. And i don't want to have the decrypted file in a physic place in the server.

Comment: @Bruno did you ever resolve this? guest271314's comments look like good hints, unless the value from `$response` actually does get sent to the browser...