# Button to download PDF file

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, moodle

On the current page I already have `button`, which `enrols` me in a course, now I want to add such `button` to `download` the summary of the course in `pdf`. The current button looks like this:

```
.= html_writer::div(html_writer::tag("button", get_string('enrol', 'local_customenrol'), array('class' => 'ebutton')), 'enrol');
```

I added the `Download in PDF` button like this:

```
.= html_writer::div(html_writer::tag("button", get_string('printpdf', 'local_customenrol'), array('class' => 'printpdf')), 'printpdf');
```

The enrol button works with `javascript` in `local_customenrol.js`, the printing of the page summary is made in `printpdf.php`, I just can not make it to trigger the `download`. I preffer to make it in `php`, if possible, or should I use `javascript`?

Comment: I'd use a HTML `<a>` tag rather than a `<button>` tag ...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876000/how-to-build-pdf-file-from-binary-string-returned-from-a-web-service-using-javas/

Answer (score 0):

I've found that to print links to course summary files you have to do something like this:

```
$course = get_course($courseid);
$url = '';
foreach ($course->get_course_overviewfiles() as $file) {
    $url = file_encode_url($CFG->wwwroot.'/pluginfile.php',
                           '/'.$file->get_contextid().'/'.
                           $file->get_component().'/'.
                           $file->get_filearea().
                           $file->get_filepath().
                           $file->get_filename(), !$isimage); 
    echo html_writer::link($url, 'Download course file', array('class' => 'btn btn-secondary span3'));
}
```

With this you will print a link for each file attached to an existing course and will not need to render the PDF using php.