# jQuery using AJAX to display PDF data obtained from a PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, file-get-contents

I am trying to use AJAX to query a PHP file and display a PDF file to the user.  The response from the PHP file is the raw data of a PDF file stored on my server.  Below is the code I am using to try and accomplish this but it isn't working.  I keep getting a *bad request* error from my browser.   Does anyone know the right way of doing this?

My end goal is I do not want the user to be able to see the server path where I store my PDF files. I only want the PDF files to be accessible using the AJAX / PHP script.  I understand it's not the most secure method but I just want to keep the layman away from my PDF files.

#### jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'process.php',
        data: {"name" : "value"},
        success: function (data) {
          var json = $.parseJSON(data);
          if(json.hasOwnProperty('success')){
            window.location(json.success);
            // json.success should contain the pdf binary data
            // i just cant figure out how display the pdf in the browser
          }
        }
});
```

#### PHP:

```
<?php   
$fileName = $_POST['name'];
if(isset($fileName)){
    $file = './path-to-forms/'.$fileName.'.pdf';
    $pdfData = file_get_contents($file);
    $data = array("success" => $pdfData, "name" => $fileName);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

Comment: Is there a function defined somewhere in your code that gets assigned to `window.location`? If so, can you edit your post and include it?

Comment: @sam no `window.location` is a built in jQuery function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know the right way of doing this?

A couple changes should get the file downloading correctly:

- Update the PHP code to send the file contents using base-64 encoding (i.e. with [base64_encode()](http://php.net/base64_encode)):

  ```
  $data = array("success" => base64_encode($pdfData));
  ```
- When the AJAX response completes, create an anchor (link) and simulate clicking on it using [.click()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) to initiate the PDF download. I can't find any jQuery method `window.location()` on [api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com)... if you find it, let me know. Maybe you were thinking of updating the (read-only) property [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)?

  ```
  var json = $.parseJSON(data);
  if(json.hasOwnProperty('success')){
      var a = document.createElement("a");
      a.href = 'data:application/pdf;base64,'+json.success;
      a.download = "filePDF"; //update for filename
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
      // remove `a` following `Save As` dialog, 
      // `window` regains `focus`
      window.onfocus = function () {                     
          document.body.removeChild(a)
      }
  }
  ```

  Credit to guest271314 for the adapted code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31763030/1575353) along with some of the code from Alexandre's code in the [answer below that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14840871/1575353).

See it demonstrated in [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/8t5s-hb0y).

Comment: Oh thanks man that makes way more sense!  Do you know if there is any way to modify that to open the pdf using the browsers built in pdf reader instead of forcing a download?

Comment: Hmm I am not sure - it might depend on whether the browser _has_ an built-in PDF reader...otherwise that might not work...