# Failed to load PDF document javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to generate simple PDF file using below code but failing with error : "Failed to load PDF document":

```
var downloadLink      = document.createElement('a');
downloadLink.target   = '_blank';
downloadLink.download = 'name_to_give_saved_file.pdf';

// convert downloaded data to a Blob
var blob = new Blob(['downloadedFile'], { type: 'application/pdf' });

// create an object URL from the Blob
var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

// set object URL as the anchor's href
downloadLink.href = downloadUrl;

// append the anchor to document body
document.body.append(downloadLink);

// fire a click event on the anchor
downloadLink.click();
```

Tried to follow many existing answers(e.g. [How to build PDF file from binary string returned from a web-service using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876000/how-to-build-pdf-file-from-binary-string-returned-from-a-web-service-using-javas?answertab=active#tab-top)) but did not get any solution yet. Please help.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: That seems to work for me. (and the downloaded file contains the content `downloadedFile`)

Comment: But the binary `downloadedFile` (14 bytes) is not a valid PDF document. So of course the browser can't load it.

Comment: you need to use some library to create a PDF file. WHat you are doing is just renaming it to .pdf but the document is not an actual pdf file. try using library like jsPDF

Comment: #user202729 :  how it worked for u?

Comment: The file contains the text "downloadedFile" (14 bytes). So it is doing what the code is telling it to do, hence it works. Also use @, not # to reply on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score -4):

Figured this out. The issue was that we need to pass a valid

`pdf(datatype/contenttype - binary) to URL.createObjectURL(blob).`

At line 6 of the code mentioned in the question, change

```
var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

to

```
var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(binary);
```

Thanks

Comment: Hello can you elaborate on this answer please? I am running into the same problem and I don't know how to implement your fix.

Comment: The explanation is simple :). If you got through the code in question here, at line 6 you need to change 
 var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
to 
var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(binary);

Comment: I am fascinated that somehow this was the answer for this person: Change the name of the variable "blob" to the undefined variable "binary".  I also love that they felt there was no further explanation required here.  lol.