# Programmatically take screenshot of certain area on a PDF

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, shell, pdf

I am looking for a way to run a script (python, js, node.js, or any other suggestion) that will take a screenshot of a defined area of a pdf.  The ideal functionality is being able to run a shell script that allows me to select a pdf file that I have downloaded, define the coordinate area of the pdf that I would like to capture in the screenshot, and then save that screenshot to the same directory as the original file.

Does anyone have any idea how/if this can be done, and in what language it would work best in?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51872656/how-to-take-a-screenshot-in-pdf-using-javascript

Comment: You need a PDF rendering library to make a raster image from the PDF, then you need an image library to handle grabbing a rect from the image. You may be able to go straight to SVG in html canvas and grab a image direct from that.

Answer (score 1):

I accomplished the above task by using 2 tools, pdftk and Imagemagick.

I went through my pdfs, cut the pdfs into individual pages, turned them into pngs, and then cropped those pngs.  My code is as follows:

```
pdftk "Pies for Daily.pdf" cat 1 output pdfs/percent_burned_pie.pdf

magick -density 600 pdfs/percent_burned_pie.pdf -quality 100 -crop 2300x2350+450+450 images/percent_burned_pie.png
```