# Download PDF from binary string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, download, binary-data

Im trying to download a PDF file from binary string, which I receive as a response from an Ajax.

I receive the following data (binaryString):

```
%PDF-1.4....
.....
....content of file
....
%% EOF
```

I tried this:

```
    var blob=new Blob([binaryString], {type: "application/pdf"});// change resultByte to bytes
    var link=document.createElement('a');
    link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download="myFileName.pdf";
    link.click();
```

And also tried using the [download.js](http://danml.com/download.html) library:

```
download(binaryString, "file.pdf", "application/pdf");
```

However, both return a PDF with the correct number of pages, but completely blank.
[image]

Result of API test with insomnia:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build PDF file from binary string returned from a web-service using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876000/how-to-build-pdf-file-from-binary-string-returned-from-a-web-service-using-javas)

Comment: no, i had already seen it, i based it even, but it doesn't answer

Comment: Can you provide a link to the actual binary string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binary string arrives at the corrupted front, so I decided to convert it to base64 on the back end and send it like this, but that's because I have autonomy from the back end, I don't know how it would be resolved for a non-public api and other cases.