# Convert Api response (octet-stream) to pdf

Tags: javascript, python, api, file, pdf-generation

I'm integrating third party api with my application. One of the endpoint is returning me pdf data which looks like this (i'm pasting only the few lines of response).

```
%PDF-1.5
1 0 obj
<<
/Type /Pages
/Kids [2 0 R ]
/Count 1
/Resources 3 0 R
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/MediaBox [0 0 792 612]
/Contents [4 0 R 5 0 R ]
/Parent 1 0 R
>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<<
/Length 78076
/Filter /FlateDecode
>>
stream
x|�ێl�ҭ�Oi��{���]�)
�����
@�_�    N�}��E���cj}k��Z��۱mvf������_���������_����������7��������������������}��������z�G~x�g������������z�L�<����_������_�7����z��������������������Ǘ�Z���������������̀��e������s��t������}��y��{z��+V�����^X�364�����b�@������������o�?�����������I�Y���������ם}�=�⟈��x����y�x ]w�����������U1~3���`�����y�9��ן����'�~��=�7�������qCK����˙���7��ʚ�N~�y?F��,������}����Go�^�Gfz|���__�;�v��y{���5�v���+�L~,�o�g�����n%�����CM�<b�l7@��ϟ��[���}����@����~�R������ےq^��D�w�
��m~Bσ�7��n?7��V�\������?���+kz�A�D�ǟ���{�?ʍ����Z[�m(�����P�?��>��/�������/��A��Xĳ�/h����q�z��������z6�/\���-7���������y�8P��i_�����g��������g����li�o���-��\��1�/�į>�l   �������m���;4
=���`�D??��� ���u�
���_����;q�5���\Q���O�s���;�~~aG�����z��.�h�A4�߂�_��D߿�r�9n�9L�`��MN{�?�?w�#�������}NĬ�#��1~xIC���/�K�;�<�~�졏����3S��~��@�L��~�h�<��Q�̖�9t��dٜ�I���Ĭs�������-����   ?�L֏�����N��g�kz��9t/�^�n�{��w|���d�~�L�2�q{Kǜ��lt�>2�?�ܞ��
{}��w�����Hn�R������cD���Q��=4wD���7�۟���s�^�>���w�:��|�}��ݙ��d���e����9I���zE�|�4�@_�������޾   �o?��������#J&�ǘ    ��q{����f�o���@��6��ſe�������#ad����Q��<ƭ-�s�޳����ɇ���N����>�n�����?��|�~p����!Ҹ}��*3t����g˞ka{!}�� ������|������C�b/k���Z�9�`�ye�w2����"�G��w�b��g��_�C61~�=8ۄ��? y�����NlG\�&��v3q~ܾ>�����j<��N���L��?o�o�=��IQ�Ǩ�}���u�`���/��wL�"�Lw#ȳ8��"?N���$�;��I���ћӳ&"MP��++��T��eg�O����c~���l ����?������B�7��~�G�7�+�1L\�<����p~�#l  ����aC_�~`1
���??��W��y�Q
䉯?�>�������#8�����N����7|dj�Pj�vG��B���)D�Z_�3�����sÄT�������$
�#���۽�@~�>�n�T��~�O|h�����:�����h�h}���z���,��hk�r�`�6�AĊ�F3Z�oD,�e.e  |���]0��������%0\�P���Ŷ4(�ű�o������/�l��?Ȋ%��O2�ϧ�L�ȅb�
���g�����3�x��H��ֵy~{O�@�'�aO[I����w�i��%���7�!1��!��u  �����V+EP�O
```

Issue is third party api doesn't have any detailed documentation, only thing that is written in their documentation is that reponse of pdf related endpoint is of octet-stream type.

My question is this response really of octet-stream type and how I'm supposed to convert it to pdf. Any answer/solution would be really helpfull.

Comment: Most APIs return files in base64 encoded stream. There is a lot of code here in stackoverflow to save a base64 encoded response to a file

Comment: Your posted response looks like a plain pdf, no further encoding applied. Thus, simply save it as is. Merely be sure to treat the data as binary, as a byte array, not as text. Treating it as text is likely to damage the PDF considerably.

Comment: this one is old question but as now solution available here. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/31763030/7902868 for me adding responseType: blob in request did the work