# Secured RESTful API - How to download a file

Tags: angularjs, ajax, file, download, restful-architecture

I am developing a RESTful API with `Spring Boot` and secured with `oAuth2.0` (via `Spring Security`) and my frontend in AngularJS.

I need to download a file and every post I read says (and I understand) that I should use `window.open('urlToTheFileEndpoint');`

But doing it that way, I cannot add the security header (like all my other ajax request), so the API does not allow my request to be completed.

Is there a way to handle this? Or should I make this file endpoint unsecure?

Comment: Do your other endpoints have something like this at the end? `?access_token=3525d0e4-d881-49e7-9f91-bcfd18259109`

Comment: Spring Security with oAuth2.0 does not work that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is how I'll solve the issue:

When users clicks "download" I'll make an ajax call to the API server, which does not returns the file, but returns a temporary `uuid`. The server will create a temporary file called `uuid.route` (i.e: abc-123.route) with the real route to the file (i.e: /mnt/data/files/excel_template.xlsx).

Then when ajax call returns with the uuid, I can call `window.open('getFile?uuid=abc-123')`. This will be an unsecure endpoint. But once it's downloaded or within an expiration time, this route file will be deleted, so it can never be called again.

That way, it supports any file, any size.

It's my best approach.

Answer (score 1):

This SO thread might be useful:

[Download file with a REST request needing headers and giving the content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23951249/download-file-with-a-rest-request-needing-headers-and-giving-the-content)

It also mentions this article:

[File Download with HTTP Request Header](http://blog.bguiz.com/2014/07/03/file-download-with-http-request-header/)

Here is a snippet:

```
var id = 123;
var req = ic.ajax.raw({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/api/dowloads/'+id,
    beforeSend: function (request) {
        request.setRequestHeader('token', 'token for '+id);
    },
    processData: false
});
```

Comment: With the 2nd link and some brainstorming with friends came across the solution I'll implement. Thanks.